# Jasmine Spec as Typescript File

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I'm attempting to set up unit testing in my project, using Jasmine.  I am writing my specs in Typescript.  My first test is simply checking that a config file returns a value as expected.  However, when I `import` the config, Jasmine can't find the spec.  If I take out the `import` and fill in dummy values, everything works fine.

My spec file is:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>
process.env.ENV = "test";
process.env.TEST_DB_NAME= "test";

import environment = require("../config/config");

describe("Config Tests:", () => {
    it("db returns string", () => {
        expect(environment.db).toEqual(process.env.TEST_DB_NAME);
    });
});
```

`environment.db` should simply return my `process.env.TEST_DB_NAME`.

I feel this has to do something with the `import` at the beginning making Jasmine not find the `describe()`.  Anyone know of a way to get Jasmine to work with imports or am I just going about testing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If you call require directly in your file I think you need to create a module and export it. Another way that I have used import successfully has been to create an interface, export it, and then did something like this.

```
import IUser = UserList.Interfaces.IUser;
```

You can then use this as the type for a mock object.